# Selenium Kijiji web scraper

Tags: python, python-2.x, web-scraping, selenium

I have this script working pretty well but I know that there must be many things that I could do better to make it more efficient.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
import csv
import xlsxwriter
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

new_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
new_driver_handle = new_driver.current_window_handle
driver_handle = driver.current_window_handle
driver.get('http://www.kijiji.com')

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "SignInLink")))
finally:
    linkElem = driver.find_element_by_id('SignInLink')
    type(linkElem)
    linkElem.click()  # follows the "Read It Online" link

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "LoginEmailOrNickname")))
finally:
    emailElem = driver.find_element_by_id('LoginEmailOrNickname')
    emailElem.send_keys('l_gaudet133@mail.com')
    passwordElem = driver.find_element_by_id('login-password')
    passwordElem.send_keys('123456789')
    passwordElem.submit()

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "houses for sale"))
                                              )
finally:
    linkElem = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("houses for sale")
    type(linkElem)
    linkElem.click()  # follows the "Read It Online" link

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Propri")))
finally:
    linkElem = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Propri")
    type(linkElem)
    linkElem.click()  # follows the "Read It Online" link

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "titlecount")))
finally:
    linkcount_label = driver.find_element_by_class_name("titlecount")
    titlecount_text = linkcount_label.get_attribute('textContent')

adnumber = 0
title_count = re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", titlecount_text)
title_count = int(title_count)
s = title_count / 20
# helloFile = open('houses.txt', 'a')
xbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test.xlsx')
xsheet = xbook.add_worksheet('Test')
outputFile = open('output.csv', 'a')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
outputWriter.writerow(
    ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4', 'label5', 'label6', 'label7', 'label8', 'label9', 'label10'])

for a in range(s):

    driver.get(driver.current_url)
    list_links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("*[class^='title enable-search-navigation-flag']")
    list_links1 = []
    for i1 in list_links:
        list_links1.append(i1.get_attribute('href'))

    b = 0

    for i in list_links:

        # Open a new tab and open individual kijiji ad

        print list_links1[b]

        if b > 0:
            new_driver.get(list_links1[b])

        if adnumber == 0:
            new_driver.switch_to.window(new_driver_handle)
            new_driver.get(list_links1[b])
            try:
                element = WebDriverWait(new_driver, 30).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "SignInLink"))
                )
            finally:
                linkElem = new_driver.find_element_by_id('SignInLink')
                type(linkElem)
                linkElem.click()  # follows the "Read It Online" link

            try:
                element = WebDriverWait(new_driver, 30).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "LoginEmailOrNickname")))
            finally:
                emailElem = new_driver.find_element_by_id('LoginEmailOrNickname')
                emailElem.send_keys('williamleonardjohnson@gmail.com')
                passwordElem = new_driver.find_element_by_id('login-password')
                passwordElem.send_keys('WJ1029vc1')
                passwordElem.submit()

        new_driver.save_screenshot('out1.png')

        texts = []

        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(new_driver, 30).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[class*='phoneShowNumberButton']"))
            )
        except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
            pass
        else:
            linkElem = new_driver.find_element_by_css_selector("*[class*='phoneShowNumberButton']")
            type(linkElem)
            new_driver.implicitly_wait(2)
            linkElem.click()
            phone_num = linkElem.text
            print linkElem.text

        # if len(new_driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("*[class*='phoneShowNumberButton']")) > 0:
        #     linkElem = new_driver.find_element_by_css_selector("*[class*='phoneShowNumberButton']")
        #     type(linkElem)
        #     linkElem.click()
        #     new_driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        #     phone_num = linkElem.text
        #     print linkElem.text

        if 'phone_num' in locals():
            texts.append(phone_num)
        else:
            texts.append(',')

        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(new_driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='ad-attributes']"))
            )
        except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
            continue
        else:
            info = new_driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='ad-attributes']")

        # info = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='ad-attributes']") was replaced by 161 to 165
        description = new_driver.find_element_by_id("AdDescriptionTabs")
        getinfo = info.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
        for a in getinfo:
            texts.append(a.get_attribute('textContent'))
        # print texts
        # print description.get_attribute('textContent')
        home_desc = description.get_attribute('textContent')

        texts.append(home_desc)
        texts1 = texts

        str1 = '|'.join(texts)

        str1 = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', str1.replace(' |', ' |'))
        # str1 = str1.strip('\n')
        texts = str1.split('|')

        outputWriter.writerow([str1])

        if adnumber <= title_count:
            xsheet.write_row(adnumber, 0, texts)
            adnumber += 1

        if 'phone_num' in locals():
            del phone_num

        b += 1

    driver.switch_to.window(driver_handle)

    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Suivante"))
        )
    finally:
        linkElem = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Suivante")
        type(linkElem)
        linkElem.click()

xbook.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Are you asking us to debug your problem? We don't do debugging.

Comment: I was asking that, however I changed the code to code that is functioning but, I suspect is very ugly (I just started learning how to code in the past month).  Suggestions for improvements would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, the code is currently working?  If so please update the title as well to reflect that.

Comment: Yes the code is currently working, thank you!

Comment: So is it good now as is?

Answer (score 1):

- If you haven't looked at PEP8, do that.  In general following the
  style guidelines described in that document is a very good idea and
  the code has a number of variable names (`linkElem`) that don't match
  it.  Also the imports aren't ordered in any way.  Keeping just a
  single style of quotes would also be nice.
- Single character variable names are super non-descript.  Unless
  there's a lot of precedent (like `i` for indexes), choose something
  more readable.
- (More) compatibility with Python 3 would be nice, so e.g. `print` should be
  called as a function (`print(...)`).
- The `reload(sys)` thing
  [shouldn't be necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script).
- There lots of no-ops (`type(linkElem)`) and commented out code.
  Remove both and don't keep them in (production) code, but perhaps in a
  separate notebook or something.
- *If* you have comments they should be accurate; "follows the 'Read It
  Online' link" appears a couple of times, but it's probably only
  correct once.
- Assignments to unused variables (`element`) isn't useful, it just
  keeps the reader guessing at where it's finally being used instead.
- There lots of duplicate code.  Put that into functions and reuse
  them.  You should probably also have a `main` function instead of
  putting it "raw" in a script like this in order to reuse it later.
- The `a` in `for a in range(s)` and the `i` in `for i in list_links`
  aren't being used, so use `_` as the name instead to clarify the
  intent.
- Use list comprehensions instead of `append` if possible.
- Use `enumerate` if possible instead of manually counting (`b`).  You
  could even argue that the `b > 0` would be better done as a single
  flag `first` or so.
- Use `zip`/`itertools.izip` instead of manually indexing
  (`list_link1[b]`).  And reuse what you've indexed.
- Using `locals` is ... wrong.  Use a different approach, e.g. set a
  flag or something.
- Ensure that things are closed by using `with` on files you `open` /
  things that can be `close`d.
- The `label1` to `label10` can be easily generated instead of
  hardcoded.

Well, there's still lots to do, but here's somewhat of a cleanup:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import re
import sys
import xlsxwriter

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

new_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
new_driver_handle = new_driver.current_window_handle
driver_handle = driver.current_window_handle
driver.get('http://www.kijiji.com')

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "SignInLink")))
finally:
    driver.find_element_by_id('SignInLink').click()  # follows the "Read It Online" link

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "LoginEmailOrNickname")))
finally:
    driver.find_element_by_id('LoginEmailOrNickname').send_keys('l_gaudet133@mail.com')

    password_element = driver.find_element_by_id('login-password')
    password_element.send_keys('123456789')
    password_element.submit()

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "houses for sale"))
finally:
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("houses for sale").click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Propri")))
finally:
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Propri").click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "titlecount")))
finally:
    titlecount_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("titlecount").get_attribute('textContent')

adnumber = 0
title_count = int(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", titlecount_text))
xbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test.xlsx')
xsheet = xbook.add_worksheet('Test')
outputFile = open('output.csv', 'a')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
outputWriter.writerow(['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4', 'label5', 'label6', 'label7', 'label8', 'label9', 'label10'])

for _ in range(title_count / 20):
    driver.get(driver.current_url)

    list_links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("*[class^='title enable-search-navigation-flag']")

    # Open a new tab and open individual kijiji ad
    for i, b_link in enumerate(i1.get_attribute('href') for i1 in list_links):
        print(b_link)

        if i > 0:
            new_driver.get(b_link)

        if adnumber == 0:
            new_driver.switch_to.window(new_driver_handle)
            new_driver.get(b_link)
            try:
                WebDriverWait(new_driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "SignInLink")))
            finally:
                new_driver.find_element_by_id('SignInLink').click()

            try:
                WebDriverWait(new_driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "LoginEmailOrNickname")))
            finally:
                new_driver.find_element_by_id('LoginEmailOrNickname').send_keys('williamleonardjohnson@gmail.com')

                password_element = new_driver.find_element_by_id('login-password')
                password_element.send_keys('WJ1029vc1')
                password_element.submit()

        new_driver.save_screenshot('out1.png')

        try:
            WebDriverWait(new_driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[class*='phoneShowNumberButton']")))
        except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
            pass
        else:
            link_element = new_driver.find_element_by_css_selector("*[class*='phoneShowNumberButton']")
            new_driver.implicitly_wait(2)
            link_element.click()
            phone_num = link_element.text
            print(phone_num)

        texts = []

        if 'phone_num' in locals():
            texts.append(phone_num)
        else:
            texts.append(',')

        try:
            WebDriverWait(new_driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='ad-attributes']")))
        except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
            continue
        else:
            info = new_driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='ad-attributes']")

        description = new_driver.find_element_by_id("AdDescriptionTabs")
        texts.extend(a.get_attribute('textContent') for a in info.find_elements_by_tag_name("td"))
        texts.append(description.get_attribute('textContent'))

        str1 = '|'.join(texts)

        str1 = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', str1.replace(' |', ' |'))
        texts = str1.split('|')

        outputWriter.writerow([str1])

        if adnumber <= title_count:
            xsheet.write_row(adnumber, 0, texts)
            adnumber += 1

        if 'phone_num' in locals():
            del phone_num

    driver.switch_to.window(driver_handle)

    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Suivante")))
    finally:
        driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Suivante").click()

xbook.close()
driver.quit()
```